# Standard Matrix for an Orthogonal Projection, Explain why $AA = A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

I have this question on a homework problem.

Let $A$ denote the standard matrix for an orthogonal projection of the plane $\Bbb R^2$ onto a line $L$ through the origin. Explain why $AA = A$.

Can someone explain what the standard matrix for an orthogonal projection is, and how I should go about solving this?

Comment: Does you textbook give a definition of that, and if so, which part of the definition did you not understand?

Comment: My textbook doesn't give me the definition for a standard matrix. Does the standard matrix differ depending on the linear transformation?

Comment: Why is the homework asking about something that isn't defined on the textbook? Did it appear in the lectures or something but you missed it?

Comment: The term standard matrix appears in chapter 3, where they referenced it saying that it was introduced at the beginning of chapter 2. but there is no mention of it.

Comment: There's a definition for linear transformation that states there exists a matrix A though, but I'm still not sure what the matrix is meant to do. I'm very confused about the concept

Comment: If you understand linear transformations then matrices are just giving a numerical form to these transformation. In your case if you fix basis $u, v$ then the matrix $A$ of a transformation $T$ will be such that it takes $u, v$ - coordinates of $w$ to those of $T(w)$ for example $[1, 0]'$ are coordinates of $u$ so $A[1, 0]'$ should equal coordinate vector $T(u)$. Let's say for example if $T(u) = u + v$ then $A[1, 0]' = [1, 1]'$. Once you understand the connection between linear transformations and matrices you simply have to note that $T^2 = T$ when $T$ is projection and same holds for matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means. I've realized that the textbook my professor requires us to read does not go in the order that I see most textbooks/sources go in